# HTML/CSS align 2 elements to 1 element e.g. 2 inputs with one label

Tags: html, css

Here's a picture of what I wanna achieve :

[image]

How to align Input 2 with Input 1?
It bugs my mind how difficult it seems to achieve something so simple. The whole thing needs to be web responsive, obviously.
Also, I don't wanna use tables.

```
<form>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Label</label>
    <input id="Input 1" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input id="Input 2" type="text" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Float can do this easily. Make sure the bottom margin is big enough to push the second input:

```css
label {
  float:left;
  margin:5px 0 10px;
}
input {
  margin:2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Label</label>
    <input id="Input 1" type="text" >
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input id="Input 2" type="text" >
  </div>
</form>
```